# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children

Tags: android, react-native

I am setting up a React app . I am getting the error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

i have this code App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {text, StatusBar , StyleSheet, View }from 'react-native'
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import { Colors } from './src/global/styles';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style= {styles.container}>
      
       <StatusBar
        barStyle = "Ligh-content"
        backgroundColor = {Colors.StatusBar}    

       />

      <Header/>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {flex:1}
})
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
in header.js
import React from 'react';
import { Text,View,  StyleSheet , Dimensions } from "react-native"; 
import { Colors ,parameters } from '../global/styles';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
export default function Header(title){
return (<View style={styles.header}>
         {
                       <Icon type="Material-community"
             
             name = "arrow-left"
             color = {Colors.headerText}
             size={28} onPress = {() => {}}
             
             />
             
             }
             <View>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>{title}</Text>
             </View>

</View>

)

}
const styles= StyleSheet.create ({

    header:{
        flexDirection : 'row',
        backgroundColor:Colors.bouttons,
        height: parameters.headerHeight
    },

    headerText:{
        color: Colors.headerText,
        fontSize:22,
        fontWeight:"bold"



    }
})
```

Comment: plz im begineer in react native

Answer (score 0):

import {text, StatusBar , StyleSheet, View }from 'react-native'
change text with Text and if it still doesnt work can u write your
import { Colors ,parameters } from '../global/styles' file in here